# Is there a site where I can download zipped JDKs? I am specifically looking for JDK 9

Tags: java, java-9

I don't have admin rights on my machine. Hence I am looking for a zipped version of JDK 9. Is there any site that can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Which implementation are you looking for?

For adoptopenjdk it's [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk9&jvmVariant=hotspot). 
For [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase9-archive-downloads.html).